# Proving $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\leq n-1$,using induction.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to prove $$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\leq n-1$$
for $n\in\mathbb N$ and $0\leq x_i\leq 1$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.

I want to prove it by induction, so
$n=1$ is clear: $x_1-x_1=0\leq 0=1-1$

Consider $n\leadsto n+1$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i-\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\cdot x_{n+1}+x_{n+1}\leq\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\cdot x_{n+1}+1$$

But how can you handle the term $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\cdot x_{n+1}$? It should be $\leq n-1$ but the term '$\cdot x_{n+1}$' confuses me a lot. Anybody may help? Thanks!

Comment: This is much like the arithmetic - geometric mean inequality, i.e. $\sum_{1 \le i \le n} x_i \ge \left( \prod_{1 \le i \le n} x_i \right)^{1/n}$. Take a look at Lohwater's ["Introduction to inequalities"](http://www.mediafire.com/?1mw1tkgozzu) for _much_ on techniques.

Comment: There is no guarantee that you can use induction to approach every problem with a variable $n$ in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i-\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i+x_{n+1}\left(1-\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right).
$$

The term $(1-\prod_{i=1}^n x_i)$ is non-negative and $x_{n+1}\leq1$, so 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i+x_{n+1}\left(1-\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n x_i +\left(1-\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i -\prod_{i=1}^n x_i+1
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: add zero.

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i-\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i&= x_{n+1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i-\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)-x_{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i\\
&\leq x_{n+1}(n-1)+\left(1-x_{n+1} \right)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i+x_{n+1}\\
&\leq nx_{n+1}+(1-x_{n+1})n\\
&=n\quad\checkmark
\end{align}

(Edit: I added the full version - it's only slightly different than OP's and Pink Elephants')

Comment: $\checkmark$ :-)