# Prove that $1-\sum_{i=1}^n a_i < \prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i) $

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

> Let $a_1, a_2, a_3,\ldots a_n$ be positive real numbers where $n > 1$. Prove that $$1-\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n a_i < \prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i) $$

Can this be proved using the binomial theorem ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Not true: $a_i=2$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ with $n$ even gives $\prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i)=1$ and $\frac{1}{1+\sum_{i=1}^na_i}<1$.

Comment: The other inequality doesn't hold either: $a_i=3$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ with $n=5$ gives $1-\sum_{i=1}^na_i=-14$, whereas $\prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i)=-32<-14$.

Comment: Did you mean $0\leq a_i \leq 1$ for all $i$?

Comment: I'm probably given a false problem. I edited the problem.

Comment: This looks similar: [Proving $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\leq n-1$,using induction.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358936/proving-sum-i-1nx-i-prod-i-1nx-i-leq-n-1-using-induction).

Comment: I told you that none of your inequalities held.  This edit didn't improve anything.  There has to be a restriction on the $a_i$'s such as $0\leq a_i \leq 1$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some of the steps
in the following proof by induction
to be true,
there needs to be
some restrictions
on the $a_i$.
Try to find what is needed
in order to make the proof valid.

If
$\prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i)
\gt 1-\sum_{i=1}^n a_i  
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(1-a_i)
&=(1-a_{n+1})\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-a_i)\\
&\gt (1-a_{n+1})(1-\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)\\
&=1-a_{n+1}-\sum_{i=1}^n a_i+a_{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\\
&=1-\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i+a_{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\\
&>1-\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

You can prove $1-\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n a_i< \prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i)$ using simple induction.

I can prove the inequality $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i)<\frac{1}{1+\sum_{i=1}^na_i}$ assuming that $\forall i, a_i<1$.

Indeed, you can prove first in a similar fashion that $1+\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n a_i< \prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)$.

Notice then that $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i)(1+a_i)=\prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i^2) < 1$, hence $$ \prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i) <\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i)}<\frac{1}{1+\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n a_i}  $$